# Integration issue with ODEINT in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, integration, odeint

I'm trying to use the `scipy` function `odeint` using the code

```
tmax,dt=5000,1.68
t=linspace(0,tmax,num=round(tmax/dt)+1)

def d_displ(x,t,a,b,c,d,e): 
    #x'=y, y'=a*x+(b/(x**2.0+c))*x+d*y+e
    y=x[0]
    dy=x[1]
    dx=[dy,a*x+(b/(x**2.0+c))*x+d*y+e]
    return dx

def displ(d_displ,J_merger,a,b,c,d,e):
    y0=[0.0,a]
    sol=odeint(d_displ,y0,t,args=(a,b,c,d,e))
    return sol

print displ(d_displ,J_merger,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)
```

but I got the error

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

why? What I want is an array of values for x.

Comment: Can you please add the necessary imports?

Answer (score 0):

First I do not get the use of `J_merger` here, but anyway:

By unwise choice of variable naming you set up a trap for yourself. in `d_displ` `x` is an array and not your value `x(t)`. So your first return value is of the form `[float, array]` and not `[float,float]`. In the second iteration, hence, `odeint` fails.

Should look something like this

```
def d_displ(solList,t,a,b,c,d,e): 
    # we want x'' = a*x + b*x/(x**2+c)+d*x'+e
    # set x'= u
    # we get u'= a*x + b*x/(x**2+c)+d*u+e
    # solList contains [x,u]
    x,u=solList
    dx=u
    du= a*x + b*x/(x**2+c)+d*u+e
    dsolList=[dx,du]
    return dsolList
```

and it works...(well, not up to 5000 as the equation explodes, but that's a different story)